# Perceived visual size of collimated image

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Suppose I have a light source which reflects off a collimating curved mirror into the eye.
[image]

Knowing the size (d) of the final collimated beam focused at infinity, how can I determine the perceived visual size of the beam? Such as in terms of being equivalent to an object of a certain size at a certain distance from the eye, or alternatively in terms of field of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your eyesight is perfect, and the lens of your eye is focused at infinity, then parallel rays entering your pupil all will be focused onto a single point on your retina. You will perceive the light source to be a tiny pin prick of light.

Comment: Makes sense. A zero-sized point source will appear with zero size. It looks like I misunderstood my own point here. What I'm looking for is the size of an image if the light source has non-zero physical size. I will probably make a new question since the whole problem changes if the question is adjusted to reflect this.