# Perceived visual size of non-zero-sized collimated light source

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Posting as a follow-up to [my previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/793417/perceived-visual-size-of-collimated-image/793427#793427) where I modelled the system in question incorrectly, and therefore the question now completely changes with the physical model corrected.

Suppose I have a light source with **non-zero physical size *s***, with its center located at the focal point of a spherical mirror with known curvature, therefore the the light coming out of the source's center is collimated.
[image: Problem diagram]

My question is, what will be the perceived (projected) size of such collimated light source, in terms of field of view (alternatively what would be the size of an object at a certain distance with equivalent image)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perceived visual size of collimated image](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/793417/perceived-visual-size-of-collimated-image)

Comment: That is literally my previous question I mentioned in the question text. No it doesn't since that one assumes an infinitely small point source.

Answer (score 0):

Let's run the problem backwards: An input beam to a lens, where the beam is inclined at an angle of theta to the optical axis produces an image height of h=efl*(theta), where efl is the effective focal length of the lens.

Your system is the same, running in the other direction.  An object of full size s, when collimated by a lens of focal length efl, will give a full angular spread of s/efl.   Longer focal length lenses (or mirrors, as you have) will produce a smaller angular output.  So, the answer depends on your choice of mirror.

Note that this ignores the important effects of diffraction: there will be some beam spreading even if the source is infinitely small.  Even if the beam is well collimated, your eye can only resolve to about 1 minute of arc: If the angular spread is less than that, your eye can't tell the difference.